# install solarized theme

Tags: package

I can not get this package installed using package-install
solarized theme
http://melpa.org/#/solarized-theme

please throw me a bone

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please provide more details about what you have tried and what is not working so people can help.

Comment: Try `M-x list-packages`. Do you see `solarized-theme` listed there? If not, you probably need to set your `package-archives` variable. See the instructions near the top of this page: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA

Comment: thanks for the reply:  I added the following to my ~/emacs.d/init.py  http://melpa.org/#/getting-started      (require 'package)  ******  lots of text posted on link ****
(package-initialize)  no luck

Comment: I do not see the solarized -theme  after i populated ~/.emacs.d/init.el